# Could not execute method of the activity Android

Tags: android

I have the following button:

```
    <Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/btn_create_user"
    android:id="@+id/btn_create_user"
    android:onClick="onClickCreateUser"

    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@color/btn_create_user"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btn_login"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/btn_login"
    android:layout_marginBottom="23dp"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/btn_login"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/btn_login" />
```

with the following onclick function:

```
    public void onClickCreateUser(View v){
    Intent i = new Intent("dk.anapp.notebox.activity_createUser");
    startActivity(i);
}
```

When i press the button i get the following error:

```
02-12 18:20:53.526    1598-1598/dk.anapp.notebox E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
        at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3044)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3039)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=dk.anapp.notebox.activity_createUser }
        at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1512)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1384)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3190)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:839)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3297)
        at dk.anapp.notebox.Login.onClickCreateUser(Login.java:74)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3039)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I searched SO but the only answer i could find is for people who forgot to declare the class in the manifest

here is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:name="dk.anapp.notebox.Mediator"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="dk.anapp.notebox.Login"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_login" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="dk.anapp.notebox.SoloActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_solo" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="dk.anapp.notebox.SoloActivity" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="dk.anapp.notebox.SpashScreen"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_spash_screen"
        android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="dk.anapp.notebox.SpashScreen"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_spash_screen" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="dk.anapp.notebox.MyGroups"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_my_groups" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="dk.anapp.notebox.activity_createUser"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_activity_create_user" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

So what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried by putting your `Class` instead of an action in your intent creation? `new Intent(activity_createUser.class)`

Comment: Why are you calling the activity using an string? Can't you call the activity passing the class? Like that  "new Intent(this, activity_createUser.class);"

Comment: Your manifest.xml contains many activities with the action tag .MAIN what are you doing by this? Make only action MAIN of that activity that will be first launch when your app runs

Answer (score 8, accepted):

in your manifest just do

```
<activity android:name="dk.anapp.notebox.activity_createUser" />
```

You should use this `<intent-filter>` attribute only once, to specify which Activity to run at startup

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

Furthermore, change your code to

```
public void onClickCreateUser(View v){
    Intent i = new Intent(this, Activity_createUser.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

I assumed your activity class is called `Activity_createUser.java`, if this is not the case you should change the above `new Intent(this, Activity_createUser.class);` to match with your activity class' name

Answer (score 1):

try this hope this will sort out your problem.

```
Intent i = new Intent(currentclassname.this,dk.anapp.notebox.activity_createUser.class);
startActivity(i);
```