# No Activity found to handle Intent even though passed in manifest and class exists

Tags: android

in my minifiest i have the following:

```
    <activity
    android:name="dk.anapp.notebox.CreateCategory"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_create_category" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

im calling this with the following code:

```
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>() {
    @Override
/* Runs on a separate thread */
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        String name = txt_name.getText().toString();
        String username = txt_username.getText().toString();
        String password = txt_password.getText().toString();
        return mediator.signUp(name, username, password);
    }
    @Override
/* Runs on the UI/Main thread when doInBackground()
 * has finished */
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean success) {
        if(success){
            Intent i = new Intent("dk.anapp.notebox.CreateCategory");
            startActivity(i);
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error! Please try again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

However i get the following error:

```
02-12 20:25:43.209    1983-1983/dk.anapp.notebox E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=dk.anapp.notebox.CreateCategory }
        at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1512)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1384)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3190)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:839)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3297)
        at dk.anapp.notebox.CreateUser$1.onPostExecute(CreateUser.java:55)
        at dk.anapp.notebox.CreateUser$1.onPostExecute(CreateUser.java:40)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:602)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:156)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:615)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21736551/could-not-execute-method-of-the-activity-android/21736708#21736708

Comment: `new Intent("dk.anapp.notebox.CreateCategory")`.  What led you to believe that `Intent` takes a string argument for the class to launch in it's constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you put wrong parameter in the Intent constructor:

```
Intent i = new Intent("dk.anapp.notebox.CreateCategory");
```

The parameter of this constructor expects the Intent action, such as ACTION_VIEW etc but you put the name of your activity here.
That is why logcat complains about nothing found to handle your action:

```
No Activity found to handle Intent { act=dk.anapp.notebox.CreateCategory }
```

Maybe use another constructor. have you already tried this?

```
new Intent(this, CreateCategory.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try calling it like this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(youractualactivity.this, CreateCategory.class);
```

With youractualactivity beeing the Activity where you are trying to start the other Activity.